# ggplotly hover text doesn't work with geom_dotplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly, dot-plot

I would like to add hover text annotations to a dot plot in R. But ggplotly doesn't seem to work with geom_dotplot.

I would like the final dotplot to look like something this:

> df <- data.frame(year  = c("2000", "2005", "2005", "2010", "2010", "2010"),
> name = c("George", "Michael", "Bob", "James", "Will", "Fabrizio"))

> ggplot(df, aes(x = year)) + geom_dotplot(, stackratio = 1, fill = "darkgreen", stackgroups = TRUE) [image]

But then I want the "name" data to appear when you hover on a given dot.

The following code works with other graphs (geom_point, for example), but with geom_dotplot the look changes entirely, and the hover text doesn't work:

> ggplotly(ggplot(df, aes(x = year, text = paste(name))) + geom_dotplot(, stackratio = 1, fill = "darkgreen", stackgroups = TRUE, binpositions="all"), tooltip = "text")
> [image]

Any help with this would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Reed

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://plotly.com/ggplot2/dot-plots/) it seems not possible to create hover texts with `geom_dotplot` in `ggplotly`. When you check this documenation, you can see that none of the options given hovers the labels. Even when using `label` or `text` in your `aes` with `tooltip` seems not working.

As an option, maybe you want to use `fill` to show the names like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = year, fill = name)) + 
  geom_dotplot(stackratio = 1, stackgroups = TRUE)

ggplotly(p)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi Quinten, Thanks very much for your response and proposed solution. The problem is that my real data set has a lot more data, and I want to put several variables in the annotations, so it really needs to be hover text. I think the solution, given what you said about the doumentation, is to make a scatter plot that looks like a dot plot.

Answer (score 0):

If hover text is not available with for `geom_dotplot`, then another solution would be to make a scatter plot that *looks* like a dot plot:

```
df <- data.frame(
    year = c("2000", "2005", "2005", "2010", "2010", "2010"),
    name = c("George", "Michael", "Bob", "James", "Will", "Fabrizio"),
    position = c("1", "1", "2", "1", "2", "3"))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = position,  text = paste(name)))
     + geom_point(colour = "darkgreen", alpha = .3, size = 5)
     + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 10))
     + theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks.y=element_blank(), 
     axis.title.y = element_blank())

ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text")
```

[image]

(The hover text doesn't work in the StackOverflow preview but it does in R Studio.)